# SQL query involving sub-Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a query to find the corresponding Western Longitude value for the greatest value of the Northern Latitudes less than 137.2345 up to 4 decimal places. I wrote the following query

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(LONG_W,'999.9999') 
FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N =(SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(LAT_N),'999.9999')
FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N<'137.2345');
```

I didn't get the ouput , Please guide me !

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a hard time following the question.  This query will give you the LONG_W for the maximum lat_n < 137.2345

```
select TO_CHAR(LONG_W,'999.9999')
from station where lat_n = (select max(lat_n) from station where lat_n < '137.2345')
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot for ur help :)

Comment: the should be FROM clause in the subquery

Comment: Thanks Bulat, answer fixed.

Comment: `where lat_n < '137.2345'` is different from `where lat_n < 137.2345` .  So make sure the string version gives you the results you want.